# In a HTML table, how to show all the values in the column when the user clicks the close button on the search field?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a search/filter input field, where I can search the table for names.

*Question*: I am wondering how to add a close 'x' button, on the search field, so that the user can see all the values in the table when they click the 'X' button:

[image: Search box wit an 'X' button circled]
Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ekzm0pno/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Filterable Table</h2>
    <p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>  
    <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <br><br>
    
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Steph</td>
        <td>Wilson</td>
        <td>s_w@test.com</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try absolutely positioning an an icon over the input and adding a click event listener that finds the closest input sibling, sets its value to `''` and triggers the `keyup` event.

```js
$('.del').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('input').val('').trigger('keyup');
})
```

```css
.del {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 151px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Filterable Table</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <span class="del">x</span>
  </div>
  <br><br>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Steph</td>
        <td>Wilson</td>
        <td>s_w@test.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think your response was deleted. Do you mind posting it again?

Comment: I see the logic. Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: @ShawnAdiosn No problem. If it answers your question, please consider accepting

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact look you want, you can check into using icons from fontawesome or the like, but this is the code that will get you there.

Create a button to sit on top of the search form, wire it up with a listener that both resets the input but also triggers the keyup event in order to resort the list

html:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <button class='clear'>X</button>
```

css:

```
.clear{
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  margin-left:-30px;
  background:transparent;
  border:0px none;
}
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
  
  $('.clear').click(function() {
    $('#myInput').val('').trigger('keyup')
  })
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kinglish/o4xbzh0d/4/